# UIPopoverController to handle password box?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ipad

In the iPad when you have to fill in a password, like in the dropbox app. I know I have to create my own view, but is this view inside a UIPopoverController? If so, can somebody tell me how to create the popover to place my passcode view in so it looks like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a popovercontroller.

You can present modalViewController for this, keeping the modalPresentationStyle as UIModalPresentationFormSheet

```
urviewcontroller.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentModalViewController:urviewcontroller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Ok and how do I get the border like this? Because the normal UIModalPresentationFormSheet shows a navigation bar at the top with the view under it. Here you see the blue/black border like UIPopOver's also have...

Comment: may be there is another workaround for this .. but what i would have done in this scenario .. would be take a blue coloured navigation bar.. same coloured main view and then keeping inner view  little bit small than main view.. so that u can get those borders

Comment: Hmmmzz Ok but that's not the way to go here I think.. There is also a gradient etc. on the view to make it look nice... Any other ideas?

Comment: Anyone else with a solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on passlok view and I have used the UIPopoverController with custom keyboard. Here how it looks like:

[image]